# TortoiseSVN A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected

Tags: sockets, svn, tortoisesvn, svn-repository

Who can show me the reason error TortoiseSVN, when I connect SVN-Repo to update resource

The error detail:
[image]

I has already checked the

- SVN server is running
- Ping to IP server ok

[image]

I attached message error:

> Error: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://........'
>   Error running context: A request to send or receive data was
>   disallowed because  the socket is not connected and (when sending on a
>   datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied.

Hope Everyone help me show the way to fix it.

Comment: You should include the version of TortoiseSVN / SVN in your post. However, I would first check your antivirus.

Answer (score 0):

I have already found the problem, my server svn disabled svn-ports

> Error running context: A request to send or receive data was
>   **disallowed because the socket** is not connected and (when sending on a
>   datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied.